# Which noun should I use to describe that a computer system hangs?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

According to the dictionary, "hang" can also be used as a noun, but I don't think it is the right word to use in this scenario. Should I use "hanging" instead, e.g., this software bug may cause two problems to this computer, crash or hanging? It also sounds weird to me.

In general, if a verb doesn't have a direct corresponding noun, what should I do if I have to use a noun to present the same meaning.

Comment: Now I'm wondering whether hanged or hung is used for a computer as a past tense verb.

Comment: I use 'hung' for computers, pictures, and stockings, and 'hanged' for people, except in the phrase 'hung, drawn, and quartered'.

Comment: "Hung" also refers to how well a man is endowed, people are "hanged, drawn and quartered".

Comment: I think the reason the sentence sounds strange is that the two alternatives are not parallel. Use: *crashing or hanging*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say "a freeze", but "a hang" is also perfectly acceptable.

As a matter of fact the title of the wikipedia article ["Freeze_(Computing)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeze_%28computing%29)  is actually... "Hang" and starts like this

> "In computing, **a hang** or freeze occurs
>   when either a single computer program
>   or the whole system ceases to respond
>   to inputs."

(emphasis is mine)

Personally I would prefer to use a "hang" for a server (typically in the case when a request is sent and one waits indefinitely for the answer) whereas the "freeze" conjures up the idea of an unresponsive GUI (when for instance moving the mouse does not move the pointer) and would therefore preferably apply to a desktop.

Comment: I've been a computer programmer for ten years, and I've never heard anyone use "hang" as a noun. Maybe as a joke: "This computer has a bit of the hang". Hey, thanks - I might use that!

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hang#Noun) has hang as a noun with this sense, although most dictionaries don't.

Answer (score 3):

In at least some technical communities, *a hang* is perfectly standard, and probably the correct term to use.  Try googling, for example, [`"fixing a hang"`](http://www.google.ca/search?q=%22fixing+a+hang%22) or [`"server hang"`](http://www.google.ca/search?q=%22server+hang%22):

> We will go over the basic debugging of a server hang in a future post.

If you don’t like that noun usage, then reworking it to use a verb is probably the best option, if there’s a reasonably non-clunky way to do so.

I’d be rather wary of substituting other nouns (*freezes*, *crashes*, etc.), depending of course on context.  As with all technical and semi-technical terms, there may be subtle distinctions between their precise meanings, which it’s important to respect.  I don’t know what the usage is now, but at least on Macs in the early 90’s, if I remember right, a *freeze* and a *hang* were two specific types of *crash* — to a lay reader they sounded like synonyms, but when the technical details mattered, they weren’t quite interchangeable.

Comment: *Freeze* is more likely to be temporary (e.g. the UI becomes unresponsive while a system is processing then starts working again), while *hang* is generally permanent, in my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

How about [*freeze*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/freeze) or [*halt*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/halt)? As to your general question, I would look around for other word stems, or just reword. (In this particular case, I might write, "the software bug might cause the computer to crash or hang".)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. "halt" is not accurate based on my context, because the system has not terminated yet. "freeze" is much closer, but I think people usually say an user interface (such as the display) freezes. "Hang" is the most accurate, but I don't know how to use it as a noun. Do you think I can just use "hang" as a noun in this case?

Comment: @evergreen: well, if you absolutely insist, yes. Though I would throw in an article just to make sure that the word is parsed as a noun right away. "A crash or a hang". A quick [Google search for "causes a hang"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=de&q=%22causes+a+hang%22) suggests that this usage is actually quite common.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases you could do the following, in order of preference:

- Restructure the sentence, as in "this may cause your computer to hang or crash".
- Use a noun that means something similar though slightly different.
- Use a gerund, as you suggested; this may be a bit awkward if you are using the verb in a marginal sense, one that is not very widely used.

In your case, perhaps you could use the noun "freeze", "unresponsiveness", or "unresponsive behaviour":

> This software bug may cause two
>   problems, crashes and freezing.

Comment: Thanks, @Cerberus. I actually thought about restructuring, but the problem is that there are many places I need to use a noun. Not all of them are in sentences that are easy to restructure. Moreover, I need to use a very accurate word. Maybe I will just use "hanging" then...

Answer (score 0):

**Stops to respond** (stops responding) feels like an alternative to hangs:

> OS stops to respond if mouse is moving.

Comment: You should include an example of use of this expression to show that it exists in the real world.

Comment: Thanks, added. Was hoping to use "OS stops to respond if mouse was moved.", but can't get rid of feeling that something is wrong with that conditional and passive combination.